# Plot stock data from csv file, not showing date correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm new to Matplotlib. I have a .csv of stock data that looks like this...

[image: stock data]

...and I would like to plot the open price, with the date as the X label. This is what I'm using right now:

```
stock_prices = pd.read_csv(cache_filename)

# Plot the open prices
stock_prices['1. open'].plot()
plt.title('Daily Time Series for the stock (from saved CSV file)')
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

...however the X axis is labelled Day, but it's only showing a number count, not the date value:

[image: plot now]

What do I need to add to make sure the X axis is labelled with the date? Or point me to resource. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not adding date data as the x-axis. That's why it is showing the default index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tricks you are missing.

```
stock_prices = pd.read_csv(cache_filename)

# Convert the date to datetime
stock_prices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_prices['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
# Assign this as index
stock_prices.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
# plot the price
stock_prices['1. open'].plot()
plt.title('Daily Time Series for the stock (from saved CSV file)')
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Taught me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(stock_prices['date'],stock_prices['1. open'])
plt.title('Daily Time Series for the stock (from saved CSV file)')
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.ylabel('price')
```